# Authorize(Roles = "Admins") causes infinite loop in MVC5 Identity 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

We have an MVC 5 Identity 2 project. How do I restrict access to a controller to Admins? When an Admin user accesses the controller below they are prompted to login, but then there is an infinite loop through the CTOR

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admins")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AdminController()
    {
    }
    public AdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _signInManager = value;
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

However if I change `[Authorize(Roles = "Admins")]` to `[Authorize]`, it works fine. How do I restrict access to this controller to Admins?

Comment: maybe your role name is "Admin" not "Admins".

Comment: Thank you @tmg but role is definitely Admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/MightyZot/archive/2014/12/28/implementing-rolemanager-in-asp.net-mvc-5.aspx)

I did not realise that `RoleManager` is not kicked off by default. To `ConfigureAuth` I added this line `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);`

To `IdentityConfig.cs` I added

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var appRoleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<CustomersContext>()));

        return appRoleManager;
    }
}
```

Then injected  `RoleManager` into the constructor for `AdminController`

```
private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;
public AdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager,
ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
        private set { _roleManager = value; }
    }
```

and all is tickety-boo